# Nethack: How to Make Complicated Multi-Window Displays?

Tags: nethack, windows

An hour of searching (perhaps I don't know the correct search phrases?) has yielded nada.  So here's a picture that hopefully is worth more than a thousand entries to google.  I've been playing for quite some time, but I want to play nethack that looks like this:

[image]

(image taken from NAO)  I'm unable to find any resources.  Anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the [Curses interface](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Curses_interface).

It's installed on NAO by default, and you can enable it by adding this to your options file:

```
OPTIONS=windowtype:curses
```

You probably also want

```
OPTIONS=IBMgraphics
```

There are several other relevant options, as described in the linked wiki page.

You can download it for local play from [the homepage](http://nethack-curses.wikia.com/wiki/NetHack_Curses_Interface_Wiki).

Comment: Great!  And it works for UnNethack, too (telnet eu.un.nethack.nu)!

Comment: Looks like it's not enabled for NAO NetHack 3.6.0